# Java: Replace a certain parameter of a POJO without iteration

Tags: java, collections

I have some list of objects:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Object.class** looks like this:

```
public class Object {

private String name;
private String age;

... getters & setters ...
}
```

I want to assign / replace all '*name*' parameters inside my ***objectList*** to one value, f.e.: **"Andrew"**.

Normally I would do it through iteration, but is there a way to do it without iterating? I have tried collections.replaceAll but failed:

```
Collections.replaceAll(objectList, object, new Object.setName("Andrew"));
```

Comment: You cannot call methods on multiple objects without iterating over them. Why is that a problem?

Comment: The demand of doing this "without iterating" in not possible. Is ways of "one-lining" it via syntactic sugar, enough?

Comment: By using Java 8 you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
objectList = objectList.forEach(object -> object.setName("Andrew"));
```

Comment: How is that not iteration?

Comment: It is functional style

Comment: That looks like Java 8 and I cannot use that in my project.

Comment: Sorry then, maybe this answer will be helpful for others

Answer (score -1):

Setting the name field  to `static` you can achieve this only. otherwise you must have to iterate over it.

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly? I tried it like this and it is obviously wrong: `modelList.replaceAll(modelList, modelOne.getName(), modelOne.setName("andrew"));`

Comment: Setting the field to `static` will make all `Object` instances share the field, so they will all *always* have the same value for it. In the unlikely case this is acceptable behavior for you, please have a read on a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) so you have better understanding on the implications.

Comment: Thanks will do that!

Comment: @DenissM. you can do like this `modelList.get(0).setName("andrew");` it will be replaced for all the objects in list. as mentiond by @Xavi this would be the shared field. and the requirement is not possible with the instance variables without iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really comply with my requirements. I guess there is no way to do it without iteration then. Thank you